# Rusza triangle inequality and approximate groups.

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Feel free to scroll down to the "Question" section if you're familiar with the notation of Tao and Vu's *Additive Combinatorics*, which I believe is standard notation for the field.

**Notation**

Let $Z$ be an additive (abelian group).  For sets $A,B\subset Z$, we define the sum-sets and difference sets:
$$
A+B = \{a+b\in Z; a\in A, b\in B\}
$$
and 
$$
A-B = \{a-b\in Z; a\in A, b\in B\}.
$$
We write $2A$ for $A+A$.  (Note that this is not dilation, and $A+A$ is in general much larger than $A$).  Notice also that $A-B = A+(-B)$, where $-B$ is the reflection of $B$ around $0$.

If $G\subset Z$ is symmetric (so $G=-G$), $0\in G$, and $2G$ may be covered by less than $K$ translates of $G$, then we say that $G$ is a $K$-approximate group.  Another way to write this last statement is that 
there exists a set $X\subset Z$ such that $|X|\le K$ and 
$$
2G \subset G+X.
$$

**Question**

The question I have has to do with a part of Exercise 2.4.7 from Tao and Vu's *Additive Combinatorics.*  Suppose $G\subset Z$ is a $K$-approximate group and $H\subset Z$ is a $K'$-approximate group.  I have shown that $G+H$ is a $KK'$-approximate group, and using the hint from the textbook I showed that $2G\cap 2H$ is a $(KK')^3$-approximate group.  I have also established the cardinality bound
$$
\frac{|G||H|}{|G+H|} \leq |2G\cap 2H|.
$$
What I am stuck on is proving that 
$$
|2G\cap 2H| \leq (KK')^3 \frac{|G||H|}{|G+H|}.
$$
The hint in the textbook says that I should use the Ruzsa triangle inequality.  So my question is:

> How can I use the Rusza triangle inequality, along with the fact that $2G\cap 2H$ is a $(KK')^3$-approximate group, to prove the upper bound on the cardinality of $2G\cap 2H$?

**My attempt so far**
I tried to turn the upper bound into something that looked more amenable to using the Rusza triangle inequality, which basically amounts to 
the statement that for $A,B,C\subset Z$,
$$
|A-C| \leq \frac{|A-B||B-C|}{|B|}.
$$
The first thing to do is to try to make use of the $(KK')^3$ factor.  So I know that 
$$
|2(2G\cap 2H)| \leq (KK')^3 |2G\cap 2H|.
$$
Making this substitution, it would suffice to show that 
$$
|2G\cap 2H| \leq \frac{|2(2G\cap 2H)||G||H|}{|2G\cap 2H||G+H|}.
$$
From here I'm not sure where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rusza Triangle Inequality states that:
$$
|A-C| \leq \frac{|A-B| \cdot |B-C|}{|B|}
$$
This yields:
$$
|2G + 2H| \leq \frac{|2G - 2G \cap 2H| \cdot |2G \cap 2H - 2H|}{|2G \cap 2H|}.
$$
which implies 
$$
|2G \cap 2H| \leq \frac{|2G - 2G \cap 2H| \cdot |2G \cap 2H - 2H|}{|2G + 2H|} \leq \frac{|2G - 2G| \cdot |2H - 2H|}{|2G + 2H|} \leq \frac{|2G + 2G| \cdot |2H + 2H|}{|G + H|} = \frac{|4G| \cdot |4H|}{|G + H|}
$$
Since $G$ is a $K$ approximate group, and $H$ is a $K'$ approximate group, 
$4G \subset G + 3X$, where $X : |X| = K, 2G \subset G+X$ and $4H \subset H + 3Y$, where $Y : |Y| = K', 2H \subset H+Y$. All together, 
$$
|2G \cap 2H| \leq \frac{|4G| \cdot |4H|}{|G + H|} \leq \frac{(K^{3})|G| \cdot (K')^{3}|H|}{|G + H|} = \frac{(KK')^{3}|G|\cdot |H|}{|G+H|}
$$
which is the desired result.